# How can I solve this can any one help me with it

Tags: github, deployment

''' Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs'''

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the style.scss file Write the code in your style.scss file and make sure in your scss file doesn't have any coding error

```html
---
# this ensures Jekyll reads the file to be transformed into CSS later
---
```

You can share your scss file also You can follow the doc https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/issues/220